# How do you include `"""` in a Scala triple-quoted string?

Tags: scala

Weirdly, I can't find this. If you want to include `"""` in a triple-quoted string, you can't replace one of the `"`s with `\"`, because that will be interpreted as backslash + quote.

Is the only way to replace one of the three with `\u0022`?

Comment: Might be worth adding this to the sections of docs that talk about triple-quoted strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's plenty of ways actually.

```
val q = '"'
println(s"""$q$q$q""")
println(s"""""$q""") // this works too
```

Or

```
println(""""""""")
```

The above prints three double-quotes ... but I don't think you can add much of anything else there. Can do this though

```
val q = """""""""
println(s"""${q}foo bar${q}""")
```

This prints `"""foo bar"""`

Also, this: `s"${"\""*3}"`

Or this: `s"${'"'.toString * 3}"`

Or this: `s"${Seq.fill(3)('"').mkString}"`

Comment: This explains why no one mentions it in the doc section. People would run away screaming. :-) I should have specified no interpolation to challenge you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try interpolation trick:

```scala
val str = s"""
foo ${"\"\"\""} bar
"""

println(str) // prints 'foo """ bar'
```

Or

```scala
val str = s"""
foo ${"""""""""} bar
"""
```